# Is this a sufficient condition for a.e. convergence?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose one has a sequence $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ of real-valued, non-negative functions defined on a finite measure space $(X, \mu)$, with the following property:

> For every $n \in \mathbf{N}$, $\displaystyle \mu \left\{ x \, : \,f_{n} (x) > \frac{1}{n} \right\} < \frac{1}{2^{n}}$.

I (guess I) proved that this condition ensures that $f_{n}$ converges to $0$ in measure. It is thus possible to extract a subsequence converging to $0$ a.e. and that solved the problem I had. I was wondering, however, if it is actually possible to prove that the whole sequence converges to $0$ a.e. I have a feeling that this is true, but haven't been able to prove it so far.

Comment: Do you know the Borel-Cantelli lemma?

Comment: Of course! Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $\sum\mu(E_n)<\infty$ then almost every $x$ lies in at most finitely many $E_n$. Proof: Monotone convergence shows that $$\int\sum\chi_{E_n}=\sum\int\chi_{E_n}<\infty,$$so $\sum\chi_{E_n}<\infty$ almost everywhere.